# Adding records with pointers to arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have to create a program which adds records to a simple phone book. The code is below, but it doesn't work - function ends and then it stucks on declaring struct record x and doesn't want to display my added record - the program breaks down. When I put this part of code on the end of the function (but instead of "struct record x = array[0];" I put "struct record x = (*array)[0]") it works - record is printed. So I guess the problem is something about pointers, but I'm struggling and I really couldn't find out what's wrong. I remember that few weeks ago I created a program which was very similar but it was adding a new record to an array of integers, with fixed values and it was working well, so maybe there's something with structures that I don't know about. Thanks for any help!

I know the program isn't done yet and I know that I didn't make any action for temp_array == NULL, it'll be done after I found out what's going on.

```
struct record {
    char f_name[SIZE];
    char name[SIZE];
    long int phone;
};

int add_record(struct record** array, int n)
{
    struct record* temp_array = malloc((n+1) * sizeof(struct record));
    if (temp_array == NULL)
    {
        free(temp_array);
        return -1;
    }
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp_array[i] = (*array)[i];
    }
    struct record new_record;
    printf("\nAplly data.");
    printf("\nFirst name: "); /*fgets(new_record.f_name, SIZE, stdin);*/ scanf("%s", &new_record.f_name);
    printf("Surname: "); /*fgets(new_record.name, SIZE, stdin);*/ scanf("%s", &new_record.name);
    printf("Phone number: "); scanf("%d", &new_record.phone);
    temp_array[n] = new_record;
    free (*array);
    *array = temp_array;
    //struct record x = (*array)[0];
    //puts(x.f_name); puts(x.name); printf("%d", x.phone);
    return 0;
}

main()
{
    struct record* array; int n = 0;
    int choice;
    printf("\n1. Add record\n2. Delete record\n3. Find record\n0. Exit\n\nChoose action: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case 0: printf("\nKsiazka zostala zamknieta.\n"); return;
        case 1: add_record(&array, n); n++; break;
        case 2: return;
        case 3: return;
        default: printf("Wrong choice.\n\n"); return;
    }
    struct record x = array[0];
    puts(x.f_name); puts(x.name); printf("%d", x.phone);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it stucks on declaring struct record x [...] the program breaks down"?  Is this a compile error (post the whole error) or runtime problem (be as descriptive as possible)?

Comment: `struct record* array=NULL;`, and use `%ld` for `long int`

Comment: There are several things wrong with this program. If `temp_array == NULL` then you do not want to do `free(temp_array)` because `temp_array` was never allocated a valid address. You call `add_record...` with `&array` which has type `struct record **array` (it's a pointer to a pointer). You should just pass `array` since it's already a pointer. When you call `add_record` with `array`, the struct pointer has no valid address assigned to it, and no data assigned to it if it did. So the function of `add_record` will fail.

Comment: @lurker it won't hurt anything, but the lack of need to do it in the first place is certainly true. `free()` ing `NULL` is a defined no-op behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig indeed, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't say it would fail, but in this case, though, I think it illustrates a lack of understanding on the part of the programmer.

Comment: @lurker certainly so. From what I see this could be considerably reduced with `realloc`in `add_record` and a NULL initializer on `array` in `main()`.

Comment: @lurker - You're right with `free(temp_array)` - I was just too fast when copying an idea from my other code. Second thing - I cannot pass `array` because in function I have `struct record **array`. And the function `add_record` doesn't fail - `main()` is the function which fails.
@BLUEPIXY You were right with this NULL. But my question is - why do I have to do that? What's going on there?

Comment: @zuroslav `free (*array);` calling the free in the address is not a legitimate address if you do not initialized with NULL.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, but could You describe me why is that? Isn't `free()` setting pointer to NULL actually?

Comment: `free` when the address of the memory is given not to initialize will malfunction. Perhaps It cause a segment fault. be able to give to `free` it is an address by `NULL` or malloc family.

Answer (score 0):

`struct record* array=NULL;`, and use `%ld` for `long int` –  BLUEPIXY